# How to order nested list with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to order the books list in this dataframe using pyspark

```
root
 |-- AUTHORID: integer
 |-- NAME: string 
 |-- BOOK_LIST: array 
 |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer 
 |    |-- BOOK_NAME: string
```

## Update

In my case I have a dataframe that has nested items in multiple levels

```
root
  |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
  |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
  |-- Books: array (nullable = false)
  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
  |    |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
  |    |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
  |    |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

How to be able to sort chapters by name ?

Comment: for the updated schema, I think at this point you should `explode` the arrays and sort, then combine it back.

Comment: @Emma we can use `array_sort` for the 1st level items, for the other ones I apply `array_sort` just affter the  `.agg()`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by `BOOK_ID` and if `BOOK_ID` is a unique field, you can use `array_sort`.

```py
df = df.withColumn('BOOK_LIST', F.array_sort('BOOK_LIST'))
```

Note that `array_sort` will only sort by 1 column within the array, in this example BOOK_ID only.

Comment: is there a way to sort based on +more than 1 column using `array_sort` ?

Comment: I don't think so. `array_sort` only works if your array contains 1 element or on the first element in the array (`BOOK_ID` in your case.).  

If you would like to sort for both `BOOK_ID` and `NAME` of Chapters, my best bet is to `explode` both nesting arrays and sort/aggregate (Window function perhaps) in the end. Do not apply `array_sort` in this case. Once you explode, you will need `sort` on the rows based on 2 columns anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create dataframe and use sort

```
     from pyspark.sql.functions import *
      df.sort(asc("BOOK_ID")).collect()
```

Please add sample data json if looking code example

Comment: the `BOOK_ID` is not at the 1st level, here we have an array of books !